# List of group members and their `IsActive` status

Tags: soql, relationships

Is it possible to retrieve all users that belong to a certain group, along with the value of each user's `IsActive` field?

Required output:

| GroupId | Id | IsActive |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A001 | 001 | true |
| A001 | 002 | false |
| A001 | 003 | true |
| A001 | 004 | false |
| A001 | 005 | false |
| A001 | 006 | true |

**Problem:**

`GroupId` is a field on the `GroupMember` object, while `IsActive` is a field on the `User` object, so I'm not sure if this is possible.

If I query on `GroupMember`, then it's possible to access fields of the `Group` object, e.g. `SELECT Group.Name FROM GroupMember`.

However, it does not seem to be possible to access members of the `User` object, e.g. `SELECT GroupId, UserOrGroupId, User.IsActive FROM GroupMember WHERE GroupId = 'A001'` results in the error:

`Didn't understand relationship 'User' in field path. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.`

**Is there any way to get the desired output as shown above with SOQL?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### At time of writing, what you are asking for is not possible to do with SOQL queries alone

(and also not in a single query).

`UserOrGroupId` is an example of a "polymorphic" relationship field. While normal relationship fields can only point to on type of SObject, polymorphic relationships can hold an Id for one of many potential SObject types (hence the "poly" bit).

### If it were possible

Salesforce has given us the ability to work with polymorphic relationships using things like `TYPEOF` and `.Type`. [The relevant documentation on working with polymorphic relationships is here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_polymorph_keys.htm).

If this were possible, your query would end up looking something like this

```
SELECT 
    GroupId, 
    TYPEOF UserOrGroup 
        WHEN User THEN Id, Name, IsActive 
    END 
FROM GroupMember 
WHERE UserOrGroup.Type = 'User' AND UserOrGroup.IsActive = true
```

All of the things in that query are supported by that documentation I linked; except for the `UserOrGroup.IsActive = true` bit.

A quick test that I ran using the `Event` SObject suggests that the syntax would be valid (though it may not be useful). The following query works:

```
SELECT Id,
  TYPEOF What
    WHEN Account THEN Phone
    WHEN Opportunity THEN Amount
  END
FROM Event
WHERE What.Type IN ('Account', 'Opportunity') AND What.Phone = null
```

The "may not be useful" part is because it'll return rows for Opportunities even though Opportunity has no standard "Phone" field. Filtering on a particular value for Phone does not appear to work (no syntax error, but it doesn't return the correct results)

### In the case of GroupMember

Salesforce complains that `UserOrGroup` is not a valid field.

When you're working with related data in a query, we drop the "Id" bit from standard relationship fields (so `UserOrGroupId` becomes `UserOrGroup`), and custom relationship fields change the `__c` to `__r` (e.g. `MyOpportunityLookup__c` => `MyOpportunityLookup__r`)

So because Salesforce can't properly recognize its own relationship field, we can't use any of the features normally available to work with relationships.

### Welcome to Salesforce Shenanigans

There are a handful of Salesforce features that they seemingly plucked from other companies (that they ostensibly acquired) and just slapped into Salesforce and hold it on with duct tape.

These features aren't nearly integrated as well as things they've developed themselves, and it shows. Sometimes, it'll just have a completely different "feel" to it (looking at you, CRM Content Libraries). Other times, like this case, the "standard" behavior and tools don't apply.

So in this case, to get *exactly* what you want, you will need:

- To run one query on GroupMember
- To run a second query, on User
- Use Apex to stitch the results together (store the User query results in a Map so you can get at the data for the User Id you'll get in your query on GroupMember)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain this so thoroughly @Derek F, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest:

```
select Id, IsActive
from User
where Id in (select UserOrGroupId from GroupMember where GroupId = '...')
order by Id
```

**PS**

I did create a `Group` and tried this and it worked:

[image: result in Dev Console]